# Missing one element from Array after request to the backend using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm fetching data from my backend using Axios in ReactJS. The response should be an array of data with I believe my backend returns 5 elements and I have proved it using postman.

Here is my code :

```
export const getRoomMessages = async (chatRoomId, limit = 20, page = 1) => {
  try {
    const response = await backendApi.get(
      `/chat_rooms/${chatRoomId}/chat_room_messages?limit=${limit}&page=${page}`,
    );
    console.log('reponse', response.data.data);
    console.log('data0', response.data.data[0]);
    console.log('data1', response.data.data[1]);
    console.log('data2', response.data.data[2]);
    console.log('data3', response.data.data[3]);
    console.log('data4', response.data.data[4]);
    return [null, response.data];
  } catch (e) {
    return [e, null];
  }
};
```

And here is the screenshot of the console log:
[image: Console Log]

Before I expand the response data it was detected as Array with have 5 elements. But after I expand the response data it became 4 elements ? I'm missing the one element. So I tried to console log all the array element from index 0 to 4, and surprisingly it was no error and I got the missing element. But there is one more strange thing, the console log order is also random if we look at the data[0] in the response tab (which I border with blue) is the data with id "241" but when I console the log separately (which I border with red) it becomes "254" which is the missing element.

I'm still not sure what's causing this problem and I'm not sure it's a bug in Axios.

Full Source Code (How I updated my State) :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.initialFetch();
  this.connectToWebSocket();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.disconnectFromWebsocket();
}

initialFetch = async () => {
  this.fetchRoomDetail();
  this.fetchMessages();
};


fetchMessages = async () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true, error: null });

  const [err, res] = await getRoomMessages(
    this.roomId,
    this.state.pagination.size,
    1,
  );

  if (res) {
    this.setState({
      messages: res.data.reverse(),
      pagination: {
        ...this.state.pagination,
        current: 2,
      },
      noMoreLoad: res.paging.total_page <= 1 ? true : false,
      loading: false,
    });
    this.scrollToBottom();
    await this.readMessage(res.data.pop().id);
  } else {
    this.setState({ error: errorToString(err), loading: false });
  }
};


render() {
  return (
    <AdminLayout>
      {this.state.error ? (
        <Error500Page
          errMessage={this.state.error}
          tryAgain={this.initialFetch}
        />
      ) : this.state.loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator
          number={3}
          diameter={10}
          borderWidth={1}
          duration={200}
          activeColor={theme.colors.ui.primary}
        />
      ) : (
        <div className="card bg-theme-secondary mxH75">
          <div className="customCardHeader">
            <i
              className="bx bx-arrow-back mr-2p sizeLarge pointer"
              onClick={() => this.props.navigate('/chats/')}
            ></i>
            <Avatar
              src={`https://ui-avatars.com/api/?background=${theme.colors.ui.primary.substring(
                1,
              )}&name=${
                this.state.room?.chat_room_title
              }&size=56&color=${theme.colors.text.inverse.substring(1)}`}
              alt={this.state.room?.chat_room_title + "'s Profile Picture"}
              size="medium"
              type="circle flexible"
            />
            <h5 className="noMarginBottom">
              {this.state.room?.chat_room_title}
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div className="customContent" id="vertical-example">
            {this.state.noMoreLoad ? null : (
              <div className="rce-container-smsg m-1">
                {this.state.loadingMore ? (
                  <div
                    className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-success"
                    role="status"
                  >
                    <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => this.fetchMoreMessages()}
                    color={theme.colors.text.inverse}
                    backgroundColor={theme.colors.ui.primary}
                    text="Muat Pesan Sebelumnya"
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            )}
            {this.state.messages?.map((x) =>
              x.user ? (
                <MessageBox
                  key={x.id.toString()}
                  onDownload={
                    x.image_url
                      ? () => this.saveAs(x.image_url)
                      : x.file_url
                      ? () => this.saveAs(x.file_url)
                      : null
                  }
                  removeButton={
                    x.user.id === this.currentUserId && !x.is_deleted
                      ? true
                      : false
                  }
                  onRemoveMessageClick={() => this.unsentMessage(x.id)}
                  forwarded={!x.is_deleted ? true : false}
                  title={this.state.room?.type_id === 1 ? x.user.name : null}
                  position={
                    x.user.id === this.currentUserId ? 'right' : 'left'
                  }
                  type={x.image_url ? 'photo' : x.file_url ? 'file' : 'text'}
                  text={
                    x.is_deleted
                      ? Parser(
                          '<i class="bx bx-comment-x" style="color:red;"></i><i style="color:red;"> Pesan ini telah dihapus</i>',
                        )
                      : x.is_forwarded
                      ? Parser(
                          `<i class="bx bx-subdirectory-right" style="color:blue;"></i><i style="color:blue;"> Forwarded</i><br/>${x.message}`,
                        )
                      : x.file_url
                      ? x.file_url.split('/').pop()
                      : x.message
                  }
                  data={
                    x.image_url
                      ? {
                          uri: x.image_url,
                          alt: x.image_url.split('/').pop(),
                          width: 300,
                          height: 300,
                          status: {
                            autoDownload: false,
                            error: false,
                            download: true,
                            click: true,
                            loading: false,
                          },
                        }
                      : x.file_url
                      ? {
                          name: x.file_url.split('/').pop(),
                          extension: x.file_url.split('.').pop(),
                          uri: x.file_url,
                          status: {
                            autoDownload: false,
                            error: false,
                            download: false,
                            click: false,
                            loading: false,
                          },
                        }
                      : null
                  }
                  date={new Date(x.created_at_timestamp * 1000)}
                />
              ) : (
                <SystemMessage text={x.message} key={x.id.toString()} />
              ),
            )}
            <div ref={this.messagesEndRef} />
          </div>
          <div className="sendMessageContainer">
            <Input
              value={this.state.focusedMessage}
              onChange={(e) =>
                this.setState({ focusedMessage: e.target.value })
              }
              // referance={this.inputReferance}
              placeholder="Masukkan Pesan"
              multiline={true}
              className="form-control"
              leftButtons={
                <>
                  {/* <input type={'file'} />
                  <input type={'file'} /> */}
                </>
              }
              rightButtons={
                this.state.sendingMessage ? (
                  <div className="spinner-border text-success" role="status">
                    <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => this.sendMessage()}
                    color={theme.colors.text.inverse}
                    backgroundColor={theme.colors.ui.primary}
                    text="Kirim"
                  />
                )
              }
            />
          </div>

          {/* <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.messages)}</div> */}
        </div>
      )}
    </AdminLayout>
  );
}
```

[image: SS Result]

Comment: I suspect it to be a bug in the dev tools, as everything else seem to work and the data is there.

Comment: @Palladium02, but when I tested the response using map method, the missing element really didn't appear

Comment: Can you show us how you use `map` (full code)?

Comment: @Palladium02 I've edited my question with the map's full code

Comment: Phew... I can't see anything wrong. Does this only happen in Firefox or does this apply to other browsers as well.

Comment: @Palladium02 I've also tried on Microsoft Edge and gives the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247543/discussion-between-kevin-jayden-wivano-and-palladium02).

Answer (score 0):

```
return [null, response.data];
```

Shouldn't it be

```
return [null, response.data.data];
```

?

Comment: sorry, but I'm asking about missing elements..

Comment: How do you update this.state.messages tho?

Comment: this.setState({ messages: res.data.reverse()  });

Comment: Does reverse produce correct results?

Comment: ah finally i found my mistake, when I want to get the last element's id, i used pop() method. I have updated my code with res.data[res.data.length-1] and it works now !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my mistake, when I want to get the last element's id, I used `pop()`  method. I have updated my code with `res.data[res.data.length-1]` and it works now !

Comment: Glad you found the mistake. Yeah `pop` mutates the array it was called on.